# Where do I find full citations for articles cited by author(s) and date/year only?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

I am reading an advanced physics book which cites articles using only the name of author and the date of publication. Google scholar most often does not find such articles despite using Advanced Search. Where do I find the full citations in the book?

Comment: Most of the times books that do this have a bibliography at the end where you can locate the cited papers. Are you sure this is not the case for your book?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I checked that at the end of my book and you are right, there I found all full citations mentioned in all the paragraphs and that section called _References_. 
Sorry for the obvious question.

Comment: In this context March et al. 1967 probably refers to the textbook "The Many-Body Problem in Quantum Mechanics" by March, Henry, and Sampanthar.

Comment: Indeed. That was the book I found in google https://books.google.dz/books?id=9gs4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA462&lpg=PA462&dq=The+Many-Body+Problem+in+Quantum+Mechanics+Cambridge+University.+Press,+London&source=bl&ots=y-3xFuaww6&sig=ACfU3U2J46bpzx2hbLmb3uNaoq5t3kSTnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijrL_DtLbqAhVG3IUKHekQBgQQ6AEwAnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20Many-Body%20Problem%20in%20Quantum%20Mechanics%20Cambridge%20University.%20Press%2C%20London&f=false

Comment: Sorry for the drastic edit.  I thought this will make it less confusing for future askers who might not have a bibliography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question answered by this comment:

> Most of the times books that do this have a bibliography at the end where you can locate the cited papers.

Comment: Usually the bibliography is at the end of the book.  Sometimes it is at the end of the chapter.